# jQuery qTip doesn't work under jquery-1.4.2?

Tags: jquery, plugins, qtip

i'm using [jQuery qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) plugin, but it doesn't work with latest version of jquery(1.4.2)

it works fine with 1.3.2.

What is the reason?

Thanks much

UPDATE:

here is the simplest example, which doesn't work

```
 ...
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.4.2.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("a").qtip({content: 'some text here'});
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a >example</a>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm sure it does work there's just a problem with your implementation. "but qTip supports the use of jQuery version 1.2.6 and above", can you provide a bit more information on what exactly the problem is, how you've implemented it.

Comment: No, He is right, jsuttested it, Debugging now!

Comment: For some reason its saying that $.fn.interfaces is undefined but I don't see how jQuery 1.3.2 would change this unless they have updated the push method.

Comment: have a look at my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right so it looks like there is a bug with the latest version of qTip, theres a [bit of a discussion about it](http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/thread-qtip-still-not-working-with-jquery-1-4-2). One of the people that comments back suggested using a different [version (build, whatever) of the plugin](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~craig.craigsworks/qtip/1.0/annotate/head%3A/jquery.qtip-1.0.js).

[I did just that and slapped it into jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fEsnX/2/) and I can now see the tooltip, so perhaps you should download [revision 55](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~craig.craigsworks/qtip/1.0/annotate/head%3A/jquery.qtip-1.0.js) and use that instead.

Hope that helps.